# create aggregate table in postgress that updates over time?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a aggregated table in postgres, that updates every day (ideally every hour).

```
sql = """
        SELECT 
            user_id,
            AVG(sentiment) as sentiment,
            AVG(magnitude) as magnitude,
            SUM(sentiment) as total_sentiment,
            SUM(magnitude) as total_magnitude,
            MAX(sentiment) as max_sentiment,
            MIN(sentiment) as min_sentiment,
            COUNT(user_id) as count
        FROM
            sentiments
        GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', TO_TIMESTAMP(created)), user_id;

    """

conn = db_conn.main()
cur = conn.cursor()
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=conn)
cur.close()
df
```

This script gets the data I want from the original table (in python).

I'm wondering, how would I create a new table, and then how would I check to update it again without being inefficient and doing that whole select statement again?

#### Based on comments I can create a view.

How would I create a view in postgres to achieve this outcome automatically!

Comment: Maybe you want a [meterialised view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-creatematerializedview.html)

Comment: Or simply [CREATE VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) which doesn't need any update !!!